# Creating a SolrCrudRepository manually

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data

In reference to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859181/spring-data-solr-multiple-cores-and-repository)

I want to manually set up a repository using my own `SolrTemplate`. This is because I have multiple instances of Solr running and I want a repo for each one of them. Here's what I do:

Bean definition:

```
<bean id="currencySolrServer" class="org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer">
    <constructor-arg value="${solr.server.currency.url}" index="0"/>
</bean>

<bean id="currencySolrTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="currencySolrServer"/>
</bean>
```

I have a very basic repository:

```
@Component
public interface CurrencyRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<SolrInputDocument, String>
{
}
```

A service class:

```
@Service
public class SolrService
{
  @Resource
  @Qualifier("currencySolrTemplate")
  SolrTemplate currencySolrTemplate;
  private CurrencyRepository repository;

 /*init the repo*/
  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {
    log.debug("Creating SolrRepository");
    repository = new SolrRepositoryFactory(currencySolrTemplate)
    .getRepository(CurrencyRepository.class);
    log.debug( "SolrRepositiory created" );
  }
}
```

According to the referenced article, Bob's my uncle, But, instead it blows up in the `init()` method with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CurrencyRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'solrTemplate' while setting bean property 'solrOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'solrTemplate' is defined
```

Right. Convention over configuration. Why is `CurrencyRepository` still looking for a reference to a default `SolrTemplate` although I have given it my own `currencySolrTemplate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! I had a old line in my context file:

```
<solr:repositories base-package="com.sundberg.solr.repository"/>
```

This, somehow, caused the repo to look for a default solrTemplate. Removing this line solved the problem. Feel free to share some light on this. Overall, the docs of Spring's Solr framework are not very comprehensive.

Comment: what your mean about context file? I use IntelliJ idea and boot spring but can not found it.