# Cannot start embedded solr server on upgrading spring-data-solr to version 1.3.1

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, solr, lucene

I had configured an embedded solr server following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21848776/284236

It was working perfectly with the following in pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I changed it to:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

When I start my tomcat server, I get:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1565)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1273)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more

Jan 13, 2015 9:51:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
......
```

There is nothing in the stacktrace for me to understand why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conflict between different SOLR versions.

`org.springframework.data` has `solr-core` as a Dependency. See this [maven-repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-solr/1.0.0.RC1).

It just happens that org.springframework.data 1.0.0.RC1 uses SOLR `4.1.0`, which you referenced in your old example.

Spring 1.3.1 references Solr 4.7.2. See here it's [maven-repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-solr/1.3.1.RELEASE).

So you could just remove the solr dependency from the pom or switch to solr version 4.7.2.

Comment: You are right about solr version conflicts, it shows up in dependency hierarchy. I switched to 4.7.2, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the SOLR-Core dependency alltogether? This 'ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer ...' indicates some kind of version conflict. Eg same dependency added twice or so.

Comment: I was able to get past it by excluding the servlet dependencies from solr-core. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.